# Error 1062, "Duplicate entry 'a@b.com' for key 'Email_UNIQUE'" on EMPTY TABLE

Tags: python, mysql, macos, installation, mysql-error-1062

Title says it all.

Empty table with following creation syntax, only table in database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ACME`.`Registration` (
  `ConfirmationNumber` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `Title` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `StreetAddress` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Province` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `ZipCode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `Country` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ConfirmationNumber`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ConfirmationNumber_UNIQUE` (`ConfirmationNumber` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Email_UNIQUE` (`Email` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `PhoneNumber_UNIQUE` (`PhoneNumber` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Any and all inserts get this error.

```
Error 1062, "Duplicate entry 'a@b.com' for key 'Email_UNIQUE'"
```

I have tried inserting with and without 0 for the auto incrementing confirmation number.

I think this *might* have something to do with my installation of mysql, as the (Mac) system preferences pane shows the server is running fine, but if I try to stop/start from terminal, I get weird errors. Specifically:

```
$ mysql.server stop
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/rover-231-4.rovernet.mtu.edu.pid).
```

Although, I *know* that I am connecting to the right server (localhost) and database, since the data *DOES GET INSERTED* into the registration table.

This is a Python/MySQL/Flask -> HTML/CSS/JS stack, all of which I am new to. Python code to insert is:

```
    query_string = (
        "INSERT INTO Registration "
        "(FirstName, LastName, CompanyName, Title, Email, PhoneNumber, "
        "StreetAddress, City, Province, ZipCode, Country) "
        "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);")
    cursor.execute(query_string, (first_name, last_name, company, title, email, phone, address, city, state, zipcode, country))
```

EDIT: I should also add that until I ran into an installation issue and had to re-install, the exact same code worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Given the portions of the code shown, we're going to guess that the email variable contains the string "a@b.com" at the time the query is executed.

I suggest you try a query of the table

```
SELECT email FROM Registration WHERE email = 'a@b.com'
```

just to see if there's an existing row returned.

With the UNIQUE constraint defined on that column in the table, the error being returned is the expected result if that row is already in the table, and you attempt to add another row with an identical value.

Is it possible your code is looping through the insert statement two (or more) times?

Are you sure that your code is connecting to the same MySQL server, using the same credentials and database?

Another less likely possibility is that there is a BEFORE INSERT trigger defined on the table which is setting NEW.email to that string value.

As another possibility, especially if these are MyISAM tables, is corruption in the table. You could DROP the table and re-create it.

For debugging this, I suggest you echo/print the values of the variables referenced in the query execution, in particular, the email variable.

Comment: I've dropped the whole database and/or table as well as renamed them. Same results. I only have the server at localhost and the user root defined. It is not possible that I am looping as there is no loop in the entire program and this is the only insert command, which is followed by a printout. There are no before insert triggers defined as the sql given above is the entire database creation script. The email variable is definitely changing, as using a different value in the HTML field yields the different value in the error. It also happens for phone number if I remove email entirely.

Comment: Well that's the error we get when a unique key constraint is violated. My next suggestion is to *remove* the unique indexes and run the code. And then check the contents of the table, to see if it contains any rows. (I suspect you are going to find two or more rows.)

Answer (score 0):

I bit of a stab in the dark, but creating the table with `IF NOT EXISTS` means that the table will be created *only* if it does not already exist.

If the table *does* already exist, and it contains data e.g. a row in which column `Email` is `a@b.com`, your insert will fail.

The `CREATE TABLE` command will not complain if the table already exists, and it will not clear out the data from the existing table, so multiple runs of your code could very well produce the error that you see.

If you can afford to lose the table, how about trying to drop it before you start your flask app and see if the problem persists. If you can't lose the data, try renaming the table and restart your flask app:

```
mysql> rename table `ACME`.`Registrations` to `ACME`.`blah`;
```

Comment: I have dropped (manually) the entire database and/or table as well as renamed them. Same result.

Comment: But when do you get the problem? Is it on the very first try or a subsequent try. All evidence points to the likelihood that the table already contains a row with the unique column, hence the error.

Comment: Very first try. :(

Comment: Well something, somewhere, is inserting that record before your code tries to insert it. Have you tried a different value for the email address? Try adding a select query for the row (or a `select *`) before your insert query to your flask view code and print it out.

Answer (score 0):

New to HTML/CSS/JS. Turns out my JS and my HTML were both calling the validate function, but I didn't notice because this was the first time (in a lot of development thus far) that calling the function twice would cause an error. Thanks to mhawke and spencer7593 for pointing me in the right direction.